# Python parsing custom commad that adds 2 numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic command line in python. I have a user input that I am spliting into a dictionary (called tokens) I want to take values from the dictaionary and add them together.

Here's the code:

```
    userInput = input(': ')
    tokens = userInput.split() #sets tokens as a dict, where word 1 is 0:, word 2 is 1:, etc
    command = tokens[0] #first word of cmd
    args = tokens[1:] #second word of cmd, used as args
    args2 = tokens[2:] #third word, more args
    
    if command == "add":
        print(args + args2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are accessing the list element as `tokens[1:]` but you need to access it like `tokens[1]`, Also the `input` gives values in string format. So when you are doing `args + args2` w=it will add the strings (ex: ['1', '2' to '12'), so you need to cast it to `float` so that you can perform arithmatic.

```py
userInput = input(': ')
tokens = userInput.split() #sets tokens as a dict, where word 1 is 0:, word 2 is 1:, etc
command = tokens[0] #first word of cmd
args = float(tokens[1]) #second word of cmd, used as args
args2 = float(tokens[2]) #third word, more args

if command == "add":
    print(args + args2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized token as an variable and not a list at line 2.

Then at line 3 you are trying to get index of that which is not possible

Comment: So how do I make tokens a list?